# How to create a table with first column fixed using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I want to create a table which can be scrolled horizontally. The number of columns is dynamic. I want to achieve when we scroll the table horizontally the first column needs to be fixed/frozen. I have tried the following css. The first column is fixed alright but, second, third columns are hidden under the fixed column.

```
   .mydiv {
      overflow-y: scroll;
   }.headcol {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c0c0;
}

.tablemy {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #c4c0c0;
}

.thmy {
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c0c0;
}

.tdmy {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:8px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:arial;
    border: 1px solid #c4c0c0;
    color:#585858;
}
.trmy:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

And my table is
[image]

I'm creating my table in javascript.

```
  $(window).load(function(){
var customers = new Array();
customers.push(["TN04 AH 0253", "55"]);
customers.push(["TN04 AF 8830", "67"]);
customers.push(["TN37 CM 1249", "33"]);
customers.push(["TN19 F 9175", "47"]);
customers.push(["TN37CM 1932", "0"]);

var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

var dateArray = getDates(firstDay, lastDay);

// Create a HTML Table element.
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
table.setAttribute('class', 'tablemy');
table.border = "1";

// Get the count of columns.
var columnCount = customers[0].length;

var row = table.insertRow(-1);
for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
    var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    if (i === 0) {
        headerCell.setAttribute('class', 'headcol');
    } else {
        headerCell.setAttribute('class', 'thmy');
    }
    //headerCell.setAttribute('class', 'thmy');
    headerCell.innerHTML = dateArray[i];
    row.appendChild(headerCell);
}

// Add the data rows.
for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    row.setAttribute('class', 'trmy');
    for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        if (j === 0) {
            cell.setAttribute('class', 'headcol');
        } else {
            cell.setAttribute('class', 'tdmy');
        }
        //cell.setAttribute('class', 'tdmy');
        cell.innerHTML = customers[i][j];
    }
}

var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
dvTable.innerHTML = "";
dvTable.appendChild(table);
})
function getDates(date1, date2) {
var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var diff = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/day;
var dateArray = new Array();
dateArray.push("Unit/Count");
for(var i=0; i<=diff; i++)
{
    var xx = date1.getTime() + day * i;
    var yy = new Date(xx);

    var strDate = yy.getDate() + "/" + (yy.getMonth() + 1);
    dateArray.push(strDate);
}
return dateArray;
}
```

Comment: Can u provide a working plunker?

Comment: first column has `position:absolute;`. right?

Comment: @Banzay yes right.

Comment: @GeethanjaliR I'm creating table using javascript. I'll post it here now.

Comment: tried `{display:inline}` ?

Comment: @localplutonium where to use it?

Comment: @praveen kumar ..in the class youre using for columns.  Im not 100% sure this will work, but it usually needs to be added when I have this problem making similar "boxes" with css.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: I remember i did a table like this and after struggling for some time, i did it with `divs` instead of `table` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set `position: fixed` for 1st column and to make all other columns visible you need to set `padding-left: 130px;` (which is equal to width of first column) for `.tablemy` :

```js
function getDates(date1, date2) {
var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var diff = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/day;
var dateArray = new Array();
dateArray.push("Unit/Count");
for(var i=0; i<=diff; i++)
{
    var xx = date1.getTime() + day * i;
    var yy = new Date(xx);

    var strDate = yy.getDate() + "/" + (yy.getMonth() + 1);
    dateArray.push(strDate);
}
return dateArray;
}

var customers = new Array();
customers.push(["TN04 AH 0253", "55"]);
customers.push(["TN04 AF 8830", "67"]);
customers.push(["TN37 CM 1249", "33"]);
customers.push(["TN19 F 9175", "47"]);
customers.push(["TN37CM 1932", "0"]);

var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

var dateArray = getDates(firstDay, lastDay);

// Create a HTML Table element.
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
table.setAttribute('class', 'tablemy');
table.border = "1";

// Get the count of columns.
var columnCount = customers[0].length;

var row = table.insertRow(-1);
for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
    var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    if (i === 0) {
        headerCell.setAttribute('class', 'headcol');
    } else {
        headerCell.setAttribute('class', 'thmy');
    }
    //headerCell.setAttribute('class', 'thmy');
    headerCell.innerHTML = dateArray[i];
    row.appendChild(headerCell);
}

// Add the data rows.
for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    row.setAttribute('class', 'trmy');
    for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        if (j === 0) {
            cell.setAttribute('class', 'headcol');
        } else {
            cell.setAttribute('class', 'tdmy');
        }
        //cell.setAttribute('class', 'tdmy');
        cell.innerHTML = customers[i][j];
    }
}

var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
dvTable.innerHTML = "";
dvTable.appendChild(table);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mydiv {
      overflow-y: scroll;
   }
  .headcol {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c0c0;
}

.tablemy {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #c4c0c0;
    margin-left: 130px;
}

.thmy {
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c0c0;
}

.tdmy {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:8px; border-left:1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:arial;
    border: 1px solid #c4c0c0;
    color:#585858;
}
.trmy:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dvTable"></table>
```

Comment: this moved the whole table.

Comment: I've changed the answer.Have a look

Comment: I'll give a try and revert. Thanks